# Select dropdown list not closing after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

My issue is when I click on any item from the list the dropdown is not populated automatically and the list is not closed.

HTML code for dropdown list:

```
<label id='choose' for='options'>Select options</label>
<br clear='all' />
<select id='options' size="10" style='display:none;'>
    <option>dasd</option>
    <option>asdaaadsdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
</select>
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/JZNjz/).

Comment: Can you please explain a little better what is your problem?

Comment: Ideally when we click on option from the dropdown, the drop down closes with the option we select. But it my case the drop down remains open even when I select the option. Check fiddle for reference

Comment: Why are you working on a label? set the first option with value -1 as "Select options"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your script

```
$("#options option").click(function(){
    $("#choose").text($(this).text());
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to recreate an already existing functionality by using JS and CSS, when some good old fashion HTML would do it for you. Remove the extra script and styling, and simply use:

```
<label id='choose' for='options'>Select options</label>
<br clear='all' />
<select id='options'>
    <option>dasd</option>
    <option>asdaaadsdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
    <option>asdasdasd</option>
</select>
```

Please note that I removed the `size="10"` and `style='display:none;'` parts. The browser will take care of things like opening and closing the list of options, the down arrow, etc.

Comment: Have kept styling as I need vertical scroll bar...and label 'Select options' as well in my code. Anyways thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id='options'>
    <option value="0">--Select Options--</option>
    <option>abc</option>
    <option>bcd</option>
    <option>cde</option>
    <option>def</option>
    <option>efg</option>
    <option>fgh</option>
    <option>ghi</option>
    <option>hij</option>
    <option>ijk</option>
    <option>jkl</option>
</select>
```

I think this can help you